# Como marcar/desmarcar um link numa página clicando sobre avançar/voltar?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de **marcar** e **desmarcar** um "*link*" numa página ...

## Exemplo

```js
var contar = 0; 

link = document.getElementsByTagName('a')


// Rotina Do Botão Próximo 

document.getElementById('frente').onclick = function(){

contar++;

if (contar == 1) { 
 
link[0].className = ''; link[contar].className = 'ativo';
 
} else if (contar == 2) {

link[1].className = ''; link[contar].className = 'ativo';

} else if (contar == 3) {

link[2].className = ''; link[contar].className = 'ativo';

} else { return  }
}


// Rotina Do Botão Anterior

document.getElementById('voltar').onclick = function(){

contar--;

if (contar == 1) {  

link[0].className = 'ativo'; link[contar].className = '';
  
} else if (contar == 2) {

link[1].className = 'ativo'; link[contar].className = ''; 

} else if (contar == 3) {

link[2].className = 'ativo'; link[contar].className = ''; 

} else { return }
}
```

```css
.ativo { color:red; }

a:hover { color: red; }
```

```html
<a id="voltar">&#171</a>

<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>

<a id="frente">&#187</a>
```

> Cada *link* recebe estilização *CSS* `.ativo` apontando onde esta parado a contagem.

Então quero automatizar este *script*, deixando sua *sintaxe* limpa, sem que haja a necessidade quantificar *cliques*. Em outras palavras seria modificar para algo mais exuto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bom, a forma mais simples que eu imaginei é manter o contador da posição atual e ir regredindo ou aumentando de acordo com o click.

Vamos por partes:

Em primeiro lugar, teremos o nosso contador que inicialmente terá o valor de 0. Ele será o responsável para mostrar a posição do link atual.

Em segundo lugar, temos que obter todos os links. Para isso eu utilizei o [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). A escolha foi porque eu quero evitar os elementos responsáveis por "mudar" a paginação, ou seja, as setinhas. Para remover as setas, adicionei a classe `.seta` nesses elementos e no selector, basta utilizar o `:not()`, desta forma:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a:not(.seta)');
```

> Existem outras opções de fazer isso, como adicionar a classe somente na lista, utilizar o primeiro e último elemento e o que mais desejar. Fiz somente um exemplo que acho mais didático.

Feito isso, já temos a posição inicial e até onde ele poderá percorrer (`links.length`).

O próximo passo é criar a função responsável por mudar o link ativo, que é o motivo real da pergunta.

Para isso, eu criei a função `mudaSeta()`, que é responsável por alterar a posição da classe ativo. Essa alteração será feita em 3 etapas. Verificar o lado que deverá percorrer, remover a classe ativa do anterior e adicionar no novo elemento.

Para verificar o lado eu adicionei um parâmetro lado na função `mudaSeta()`. Dessa forma eu adiciono esse parâmetro ao chamar a função. Para ser mais fácil exemplificar, os parâmetros são **e** e **d** (esquerda e direita). Assim, na função eu verifico para qual lado que eu irei. Se for para a esquerda, eu removo 1 do contador se for para a direita, eu adiciono. Esse valor removido ou adicionado é o valor referente a posição do link na página (aquela variável link que definimos no início (`var link`)).

A função `mudaLado()` ficou da seguinte forma:

```
function mudaSeta(lado) {
  if (lado == 'e') {
    if (contador > 0) {
      links[contador].classList.remove("ativo");
      contador--;
      links[contador].className += " ativo";
    }
  } else {
    if (contador < links.length - 1) {
      links[contador].classList.remove("ativo");
      contador++;
      links[contador].className += " ativo";
    }
  }

  console.log(contador)
}
```

Note que eu apenas verifico o lado, faço uma verificação condicional para verificar se não está no último elemento e subtraio ou acrescento 1 no contador. Após isso, basta obter o elemento pela posição e adicionar a classe ativo. Mas especificamente, desta forma:

```
  //Removo a classe do elemento anterior
  links[contador].classList.remove("ativo");
  //Adiciono ou subtraio 1 do contador
  contador--;
  //Adiciono a classe ativo no novo elemento
  links[contador].className += " ativo";
```

Os comentários acima explicam melhor o que disse.

Como já falei demais, veja o exemplo abaixo, creio que será mais simples entender.

```js
var contador = 0;
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a:not(.seta)');

function mudaSeta(lado) {
  if (lado == 'e') {
    if (contador > 0) {
      links[contador].classList.remove("ativo");
      contador--;
      links[contador].className += " ativo";
    }
  } else {
    if (contador < links.length - 1) {
      links[contador].classList.remove("ativo");
      contador++;
      links[contador].className += " ativo";
    }
  }

  console.log(contador)
}
```

```css
.ativo {
  color: red;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.seta {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="seta" onclick="mudaSeta('e')">&#171</a>

<a class="ativo">1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>
<a>4</a>
<a>5</a>
<a>6</a>

<a class="seta" onclick="mudaSeta('d')">&#187</a>
```

Comment: Estou adicionando a explicação neste momento. Postei somente o resultado para lhe adiantar.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique Basta copiar e colar em seu código :p

Comment: @DiegoHenrique Ele possui compatibilidade com [quase todos os navegadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#Compatibilidade_entre_navegadores)

Answer (score 3):

Fiz com jquery, e comentei o código. Seria isso?

```js
// ao clicar na seta de voltar
$("#voltar").on('click',function(){
//pega o conteudo do <a> que esta atualmente ativo
 var valor=+$(".ativo").html(); 
// percorre todos os links para encontrar qual esta ativo
$("a").each(function(){
// verifica se esse é o link anterior, que vai ficar ativo e se é maior ou igual a 1
if($(this).html()==(valor-1) && (valor-1)>=1 ){
 //removo a classe do atual link ativo
 $(".ativo").removeClass("ativo");  
// adiciono a classe no atual (no caso, o link anterior)
$(this).addClass("ativo");
}

});
                
});
// ao clicar na seta de avançar
$("#frente").on('click',function(){
 //pega o conteudo do <a> que esta atualmente ativo
  var valor=+$(".ativo").html(); 
 //pega o numero total de links
   var total= $("a").length;
//percorre todos os links para encontrar qual esta ativo e definir o proximo como ativo
$("a").each(function(){
 // verifica se esse é o proximo link, que vai ficar ativo e se é menor ou igual ao total dde links
if($(this).html()==(valor+1) && valor+1<=total){ 
 //removo a classe do atual link ativo
 $(".ativo").removeClass("ativo");  
// adiciono a classe no atual (no caso, o link anterior)
$(this).addClass("ativo");

}

});
 // ao clicar em qualquer numero eu defino ele como ativo e removo o que estava ativo 
$("a").on('click',function(){
 $(".ativo").removeClass("ativo");  
$(this).addClass("ativo");
});
                
});
```

```css
.ativo { color:red; }

a:hover { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="voltar">&#171</span>

<a>1</a>
<a class="ativo">2</a>
<a>3</a>
<a>4</a>

<span id="frente">&#187</span>
```

Comment: Ficou até bom, e sim era realmente isso. Mas esperava em JavaScript pois não compreendo ainda JQuery